# iOS: Combine LineBreak and Autoshrink

Tags: ios

I'm trying to combine LineBreak mode "Word Wrapp" und Autoshrink "Minimum Font Scale" on a label: On a whitespace a new line should be started if needed. If the word is too long to fit into one line, the whole fontsize should be reduced.

Is this possible? Currently it is not working. For example I get:

```
John
Applesee
d
```

Instead of

```
John
Appleseed
```

Here my label and the label settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you post your code or an image of the storyboard settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the lines set to 0. The way setting the lines to 0 works is that Xcode will simply use as many lines as necessary to fit the string into place (Assuming there is enough vertical space in the label's view to do so). This essentially disables setting a minimum font scale.

You need to set a non-zero number of lines and it will work (I tried it myself). You could create a custom class to handle this but that's overcomplicating things and it's better style to set a specific number of lines if your label is that small.

Comment: no - it doesn't work in my case. the font doesn't scale down. I updated my settings as you can see in the new screenshot. Have you tested it with a a long name? (John Appleseedersmith?)

Comment: And which solution can handle names like "John Mike Steven Marcus Jonathan Appleseedsmith"? The limitation to two lines is only working in 95% of all use cases...

Comment: Minimum font size is deprecated as of iOS 6. Stick to minimum font scale. Also change your "Line breaks" from Word wrap to clip or truncate head/middle/tail. With a name (or any string) that long, your actual label size should be much wider, not a small square.